# How can i add gender field in account/register using opencart 2.0?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm new in opencart, i want to add gender filed in account/register page. I have searched about this found custom field for this purpose. I added custom field but it does not working can any one guide me that how can add gender field in account/register form. Many Thanks

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need add custom code to add custom field on customer account register page. You can add field from admin.

Here the way to add custom field on account register page.

Go to **Admin Dashboard -> Sales -> Customers -> Custom Fields**

Check with following screen-shots

```
1. Custom fields grid
```

[image: Custom fields grid]

```
2. Add details for custom field
```

[image]

Comment: yes its working fine, but can you please guide me where is its `foreach` loop in register.tpl, because I have to design these inputs.

Comment: which opencart version you are using ? In opencart version 2.0.3.1 it's around line no 90.

Comment: i'm using this 2.1.0.1 version

Comment: in opencart 2.1.0.1, `foreach` loop starts with line no 87

Comment: Thanks For So Much Help